# How to handle recaptcha on third-party site in my client application

Tags: c#, web-scraping, dotnet-httpclient, cloudflare, recaptcha

I was curious about how people build third-party apps for sites with **NO public APIs**, but I could not really find any tutorials on this topic. So I decided to just give it a try. I created a simple desktop application, which uses `HttpClient` to send GET requests to the site I frequently use, and then parses the response and displays the data in my WPF window. This approach worked pretty well (probably because the site is fairly simple).

However, today I tried to run my application from a different place, and I kept getting 403 errors in response to my application's requests. It turned out, that the network I was using went through a VPN server, while the site I was trying to access used CloudFlare as protection layer, which apparently forces VPN users to enter reCaptcha in order to access the target site.

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("http://www.cloudflare.com");
using (var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{
   var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/");
   //this line returns CloudFlare home page if I use regualr network and reCaptcha page, when I use VPN
   var result = await client.SendAsync(message);
   //this line throws if I use VPN (403 Forbidden)
   result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

Now the question is: what is the proper way to deal with CloudFlare protection in client application? Do I have to display the reCaptcha in my application just like the web browser does? Do I have to set any particular headers in order to get a proper response instead of 403? Any tips are welcome, as this is a completely new area to me.

P.S. I write in C# because this is the laguage I'm most comfortable with, but I don't mind aswers using any other language as long as they answer the question.

Comment: I don't think there is anything *you* should be doing.  Whoever is publishing the api needs to correct the matter(https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200504045-Using-CloudFlare-with-your-API).  *As requests to an API are typically made outside of a browser, we advise creating a page rule for your API's URL pattern to ensure that these features do not limit access to your API.*

Comment: @ErikPhilips, there is no public API available. Site in question probably does not have the private API either. So there is nothing to ask about. :) I still want to fetch the data from this site and process it in my app. And I am able do that, except for when I connect to the site through VPN. I could just ignore that, as normally I dont use VPN and I am doing this whole thing for educational purposes anyway. But I am kinda curious, how people deal with such things. :)

Comment: You're connecting to a site that has no public or private API... how on earth are you connecting to them...

Comment: Let me figure this out- You are trying to connect to the CloudFlare API and are receiving the challenge page because your client does not support javascript correct?

Comment: @ErikPhilips the same way your browser does, when you navigate to this page. :) I send a request via HTTP and parse the response using C# code (see the code snippet in my question).

Comment: @BinaryEvolved again, there is no API. For the sake of simplicity lets say I am trying to get CloudFlare home page, which is `http://www.cloudflare.com/`, as HTML code. Normally I am able to do that by sending HTTP request to this url (see the code snippet in my question). However if I'm doing the same thing using VPN connection, I receive the challenge page with 403 error instead.

Comment: The whole idea of a CAPTCHA is to prevent automated software from accessing the site. If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do is exactly what the site does not want you to do.

Comment: @daramasala I understand that. I am not building an automated software though. There is a human being behind the client application. Me in this case. I *want* to solve the captcha myself, but I do not know what is the best way to embed it into my application or if it's at all possible.

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak The main goal behind captcha is to not allow automatic resolution of the captcha. You could instead always present captcha image to your client and have them fill it out with your app submitting the response.

Comment: @BinaryEvolved, yes, that what I'm after. I don't know how to do that without implementing a browser of my own though. So here I am, asking. :)

Comment: I would either watch all the traffic happening with the normal browser (e.g. with Burpsuite or similar) and then start by emulating the exact HTTP traffic with the C# App you're coding. The CloudFlare server will send those cookies in the reply after solving the captcha, so you must be able to get them in your C# code.So its: 1) http get to yoursite.com 2) check response for error code 403 and maybe other indicators 3) get the captcha from the response and display to your user 4) send the solution of the captcha in the exact same way your browser does 5) retrieve reply with cookies

Comment: @TabascoEye  `display to your user` part is the part I am having troubles with. Basically, my application has to have a build-in browser, so In case it encounters captacha it can properly display it. Is that it? Or is there an easier way? It feels like implementing captcha support is going to take more coding, than it took me to write my entire application. :)

Comment: That depends on your definition of "browser" I would only implement http communication, take the captcha image from the reply, show it to the user plus a c# input widget, send that reply with http back to clouflare, then you get the cookies and use them in subsequent communication.

Comment: @TabascoEye, I'm afraid Google recaptcha is a bit more complex than that. :( There is no Image to display, it is the one with "I'm not a robot" checkbox: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo . So my "browser" should at least be able to handle javascript. :)

Comment: There are basically three ways to defeat captchas:
1. Find a bug in the implementation of the captcha. This will not be easy on modern implementaions
2. OCR it to get the text. Again, may not be possible, considering I've seen captchas that even my human mind couldn't solve.
3. Hire a captcha-solving service. Basically a team of guys who sit and solve captchas for a fee. I won't comment much on this as the legality of this is... Questionable. Have a look at this [Black Hat talk](https://youtu.be/SIMF8bp5-qg?t=589) on this topic, you may find it interesting.

Comment: Never mind, just read your comments and saw you're not actually trying to defeat the captchas. My bad! I'll leave my comment up though - for Google reasons and prosperity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, one way to go about it is to handle captcha in web browser, outside the client application.

1. Parse the response to see if it is a captcha page.
2. If it is - open this page in browser.
3. Let user solve the captcha there.
4. Fetch the CloudFlare cookies form browser's cookie storage. You gonna need `__cfduid` (user ID) and `cf_clearance` (proof of solving the captcha).
5. Attach those cookies to requests sent by client application.
6. Use application as normal for the next 24 hours (until CloudFlare cookies expire).

Now the hard part here is (4). It's easy to manually copy-paste the cookies to make the code snippet in my question work with VPN:

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("http://www.cloudflare.com");
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer } , true) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{
    var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/");
    //I've also copy-pasted all the headers from browser
    //some of those might be optional
    message.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0");
    message.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    message.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate" });
    message.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
    //adding CloudFlare cookies
    cookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("__cfduid", "copy-pasted-cookie-value", "/", "cloudflare.com"));
    cookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("cf_clearance", "copy-pasted-cookie-value", "/", "cloudflare.com"));
    var result = await client.SendAsync(message);
    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

But I think its going to be a tricky task to automate the process of fetching the cookies, due to different browsers storing cookies in different places and/or formats. Not to metion the fact that you need to use external browser for this approach to work, which is really annoying. Still, its something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to "build third-party apps for sites with NO public APIs" is that even though some Software Vendors don't have a public api's they have partner programs.

Good example is Netflix, they used to have a public api. Some of the Apps developed when the Public Api was enabled allowed to continue api usage.

In your scenario, your client app acts as a web crawler (downloading html content and trying to parse information). What you are trying to do is to Crawl the Cloudfare data which is not meant to be crawled by a third party app (bot). From the cloudfare side, they have done the correct thing to have a Captcha which prevents automated requests.

Further, if you try to send requests at a high frequency (requests/sec), and if the Cloudfare has Threat detection mechanisms, your ip address will be blocked. I assume that they already identified the VPN server IP address you are trying to use and blacklisted that, that's why you are getting a 403.

Basically you solely depend on security holes in Cloudfare pages you try to access via the client app. This is sort of hacking Cloudfare (doing something cloudfare has restricted) which I would not recommend.

If you have a cool idea, better to contact their developer team and discuss about that.

Comment: I am not building an automated software in sense, that it sends (or spams) HTTP requests on its own. It only sends requests when user interacts with it, i.e. presses a button. It is not that different, from clicking on hyperlink in browser, it's just that I also filter all the gibberish from response, and only grab the data I am interested in and display it in a format, that is convenient to me. I don't see how this is hacking. I do as much hacking as, say, AdBlock extension does when it filters ads and other unwanted content in a browser. :)

Comment: Also from what I've read, CloudFlare "bans" entire VPN networks when someone from a network is attacking CloudFlare-protected sites. So it's not that my IP got blacklisted because I did something bad, like spamming requests, but someone else on the same network did. :) I mean, my application works just fine, when I use my home IP. While my browser hits the same protection, my application does, when I use VPN. Still this whole situation with recaptchas got me curious. Oh, And its nice to get a detailed response, thanks.

Comment: Even though this is not quite the answer I was hoping for, I will still award it. Because I can (and bounty period has expired anyway). :)

Comment: Once I was on the "Cloudfare" side of the world fighting with bots. If there is a genuine idea, and it it benefits both parties, "CLoudfare" will be more than happy to talk to you, coz they also do business.

Answer (score 1):

In case you still need it, I had the very same problem and came up with the following solution 2 years ago.

It opens up the Cloudflare protected web page with the C# WebBrowser class, waits about 6 seconds so that CloudFlare saves the clearance cookie and then the program saves the cookie to disk.

You need a javascript capable browser like the C# WebBrowser class, as the Cloudflare captcha page needs javascript to function and count down in order to save the cookie, any other attempt will fail.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace kek
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx(string url, string cookieName, StringBuilder cookieData, ref int size, Int32 dwFlags, IntPtr lpReserved);

        private Uri Uri = new Uri("http://www.my-cloudflare-protected-website.com");
        private const Int32 InternetCookieHttponly = 0x2000;
        private const Int32 ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 0x7A;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

            webBrowser1.Navigate(Uri, null, null, "User-Agent: kappaxdkappa\r\n"); //user-agent needs to be set another way if that doesnt work
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            int waitTime = 0;

            if(webBrowser1.DocumentTitle.Contains("We are under attack")) //check what string identifies the unique cloudflare captcha page and put it here
            {
                waitTime = 6000;
            }

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(waitTime); //cookie can be saved right away, but the waiting period might not have passed yet

                String cloudflareCookie = GetCookie(Uri, "cf_clearance");

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cloudflareCookie))
                {
                    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\CFcookie.blob"); //save to %appdata%\MyProgram\Cookies\clearence.blob
                    file.Write(cloudflareCookie);
                    file.Close();
                }
            });
        }

        String GetCookie(Uri uri, String cookieName)
        {
            int datasize = 0;
            StringBuilder cookieData = new StringBuilder(datasize);

            InternetGetCookieEx(uri.ToString(), cookieName, cookieData, ref datasize, InternetCookieHttponly, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER && datasize > 0)
            {
                cookieData = new StringBuilder(datasize);
                if (InternetGetCookieEx(uri.ToString(), cookieName, cookieData, ref datasize, InternetCookieHttponly, IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    if (cookieData.Length > 0)
                    {
                        CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
                        container.SetCookies(uri, cookieData.ToString());

                        return container.GetCookieHeader(uri);
                    }
                }
            }

            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- Use a better user agent
- The cookie is saved to disk as well because I needed it for something
  else. Not sure if the in-built browser saved the cookies for next
  time, but in case it does not, this way you can simply load it again.
- Change the "We are under attack" phrase to the one that identifies
  the CF captcha page you are trying to bypass.
- __cfduid cookie is not required afaik

EDIT: Sorry, I was so focused on Cloudflare itself after reading other answers in here that I didn't notice that you need to bypass Recaptcha that is sometimes found on the Cloudflare page. My code can help you a bit for the browser and cookie part, but you will have a hard time solving Recaptcha, at least now. A few weeks ago they made it even harder. I can recommend compiling your own version of Firefox and then automatically solve the captcha by hitting the checkbox. If you don't get that simple captcha then you need to display it for the user. Mind that you also need to randomize the behaviour of your browser and how you click on the checkbox, otherwise it will detect you as a bot.