# HTTPS/Cloudflare: Cloudflare via C socket results in HTTP 403

Tags: c, sockets, https, header, cloudflare

I've written a primitive HTTP(S) wrapper for sockets in C.  TLS, Header and post data are already wrapped in it.

I already fetched data from various sites via this library successfully, but as soon as I am encountering a website behind CloudFlare I can't access it and get a 403 from CloudFlare. I also fiddled with the `cfuid_cookie` and other header values.

Do I have to set specific header parameters to get behind the CloudFlare proxy and access the actual web content? I am really out of ideas how to access data behind a CloudFlare proxy.

Comment: Are you connecting through a VPN or network proxy? What is the actual content of the 403 response?  Is it prompting you to fill out a captcha, by chance?  Is there any CloudFlare Javascript in the response that needs to be executed before a request will succeed? Related: [How to hadle recaptcha on third-party site in my client application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767845/) (in particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47168876/65863), though it is for C#).

Comment: No proxy or VPN.
I am using the very primitive sockets which come with "sys/socket.h"
It's direct IO via file descriptors.
I just talked to one of the devs of CloudFlare and he told me a bit about CloudFlare. I guess I will have to write a bypass library for accessing everything I need if there is no other way. Basically I have to emulate browser behavior. Not gonna lie CloudFlare is a blessing and a curse at the same time.

Comment: "*Basically I have to emulate browser behavior*" - well, yeah. The whole point of CloudFlare is to block automated software and only allow humans through. You are not making a human-controlled browser, you are making your own software, so CloudFlare blocks you, so you will have to mimic a human-controlled browser to get through.

Comment: The only thing I am wondering about is curl. Curl is a command line tool and works absolutely fine.

Comment: then feel free to capture and log the HTTP requests that curl sends, and compare them to the requests your client sends, and then adjust your client accordingly